# when i write keyword it didn't show me any option in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

when i write any keyword like txtV so it didn't show me option like textView and on the top right
corner it displaying off

[image]

Comment: Typo: `txtV` is not the same as `TextV` (it's both case-sensitive and spelling-sensitive, based on my testing)

Answer (score 1):

Click on `OFF` to turn on the analysis/highlighting back:

[image: All problems]

Comment: thank you sir i just asked it now and i get answer in few minutes i used it first time keep up it help really a lot and my